# Simplify generic type inferring

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm writing a generic code that should handle situations when data is loaded from multiple sources. I have a method with following signature:

```
public static TResult LoadFromAnySource<TContract, TSection, TResult>
    (this TSection section, 
          string serviceBaseUri, 
          string nodeName)
    where TSection : ConfigurationSection
    where TResult : IDatabaseConfigurable<TContract, TSection>, new() 
    where TContract : new()
```

But it's an overkill: when I pass `TResult`, I already know what `TContract` and `TSection` exactly are. In my example:

```
public interface ISourceObserverConfiguration 
    : IDatabaseConfigurable<SourceObserverContract, SourceObserverSection>
```

But I have to write following:

```
sourceObserverSection.LoadFromAnySource<SourceObserverContract, 
                                        SourceObserverSection, 
                                        SourceObserverConfiguration>
    (_registrationServiceConfiguration.ServiceBaseUri, nodeName);
```

You can see that I have to specify pair `<SourceObserverContract, SourceObserverSection>` twice, it's a violation of **DRY** principe. So I'd like to write something like:

```
sourceObserverSection.LoadFromAnySource<SourceObserverConfiguration>
   (_registrationServiceConfiguration.ServiceBaseUri, nodeName);
```

and make `SourceObserverContract` and `SourceObserverSection` inferred from interface.

Is it possible in **C#** or I should specify it everywhere manually?

`IDatabaseConfigurable` looks like:

```
public interface IDatabaseConfigurable<in TContract, in TSection> 
    where TContract : ConfigContract
    where TSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    string RemoteName { get; }

    void LoadFromContract(TContract contract);

    void LoadFromSection(TSection section);
}
```

Then extension just calls these two methods based on some logic. I must specify types becuase I need to access properties of each specific realisation, so I need a covariance.

Comment: If your method signature was `IDatabaseConfigurable<TContract, TSection> LoadFromAnySource(this TSection section, string serviceBaseUri, string nodeName, Func<TContract> contractCreator)` (or just `TContract contract`), the types could be inferred from the usage.

Comment: How is that a violation of the DRY principle? It's a bit more complicated than "don't write the same thing twice". You probably don't care that you write `t` three times in `twitter`, do you? :D The two are *not* the same - one is more general than the other. In any case, @JeroenMostert 's comment is pretty much the best approach, and should totally be an answer. Though probably somewhere like Programmers and not SO - I don't think it's a good question for SO, really.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, but they wouldn't know which `IDatabaseConfigurable` was to be used.

Comment: @Rob: Who is "they"? If it's the caller, the caller shouldn't care about which implementation of `IDatabaseConfigurable` is returned (and if they do, they can cast the result). If the callee, pass a factory method just as for `TContract` (`Func<TResult> ...`). Or redesign things so creation is done by builders and not functions/constructor calls. I agree with @Luaan that this should probably be a separate question on programmers.SE, as there is no problem, just code to be improved or redesigned. The answer to this question is "no".

Comment: Alex, have you looked at my updated answer? Don't let the -1 throw you off, I am fairly certain that my answer is now correct.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, by they I was referring to the callee. The factory method would re-introduce the problem, because we need to be sure we get a valid `TResult`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, obviously I meant `Func<IDatabaseConfigurable<...>>`. A "valid" result is one that implements the interface -- if something more than that is needed, there's a problem with the design. (In fact, I'm pretty sure there's a problem with the design that warrants some refactoring, but that's not exactly on topic.)

Comment: I desperately want this question to be "Simplify generic type inference", but I don't know whether people would be searching for inferring or inference ...

Comment: @JeroenMostert I know, if you need from a language something it doesn't provide, maybe you are doing something wrong. But I don't see here anything I am doing wrong. I just have an interface that provides two methods: load from config and load from database. Here is an extension method that trying to load from DB, and if it fails then it reads from config. I got this design, and don't see how can it be enhanced. If you are - you're welcome, I always love to learn something new.

Comment: "Wrong" is too strong. I'm just saying you can probably structure your code in such a way that type inference will work implicitly (or maybe you should use less generics). Whether this is actually possible, and whether you'd like the results is a completely different matter. I can't meaningfully answer those questions without further delving into your code, but that would degenerate into a design discussion, which is subjective and explicitly *not* what Stack Overflow is about. The answer to what you literally asked ("can I somehow avoid doing this with what I have") is no, plain and simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Type inference does not take into account the return type of a method. `TResult`might contain all the information needed but type inference will not use it.

You'll need to make `TContract` part of the method's signature so that the type can be inferred. `TResult` is redundant, there is no need for it to be generic, simply use `IDataBaseConfigurable<TContract, TSection>` as the method's return type.

Comment: Here is discussion about possible solution: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5023

Answer (score 1):

With the current method signature of the `LoadFromAnySource` method, this cannot be inferred as you'd like. However, this can be inferred with a modification to the `LoadFromAnySource` signature.

Since you already know the `ISourceObserverConfiguration` interface (and from this we know that it re-implements the `IDatabaseConfigurable<SourceObserverContract, SourceObserverSection>` interface), use that as a generic constraint instead in your method declaration:

**Instead of**

```
public static TResult LoadFromAnySource<TContract, TSection, TResult>
    (this TSection section, 
          string serviceBaseUri, 
          string nodeName)
    where TSection : ConfigurationSection
    where TResult : IDatabaseConfigurable<TContract, TSection>, new() 
    where TContract : new()
```

**Use this**

```
public static TResult LoadFromAnySource<TResult>
    (this SourceObserverSection section, 
          string serviceBaseUri, 
          string nodeName)
    where TResult : ISourceObserverConfiguration, new()
```

This removes the need for the `TContract` and `TSection` as they are known in the `ISourceObserverConfiguration` interface. The compiler knows that the interface constraint is `IDatabaseConfigurable<SourceObserverContract, SourceObserverSection>` and it will just work.

Additionally, since this is an extension method and we're defining a generic constraint on `ISourceObserverConfiguration`, we need to extend `SourceObserverSection`.

---

Then you can consume it exactly like you desire:

```
sourceObserverSection.LoadFromAnySource<SourceObserverConfiguration>
   (_registrationServiceConfiguration.ServiceBaseUri, nodeName);
```

**Update**

Based on the *OP's* modifications/clarifications to the question, I have the following:

> Is it possible in **C#** or I should specify it everywhere manually?

You should specify it manually. It is **not** possible with to infer this based on the requirement of having a re-implementation where the base interface defines the concrete type that your top-level constraint is attempting to resolve. In other words, since you have multiple implementations of `IDatabaseConfigurable` the caller must specify which implementation to use via its `TContract` and `TSection` constraints.

Comment: That won't compile since you don't define the `TSection` anymore.

Comment: I updated my answer and would appreciate an upvote, since it is now correct

Comment: `ISourceObserverConfiguration` is one of specific interfaces, I have multiple interfaces, inheriting `IDatabaseConfigurable`. So unfortunly I cannot write `ISourceObserverConfiguration` here, it should be more generic.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends how flexible your code is, and what you do with it. In general, no - you either need to specify *all* the generic types, or none of them.

This means that simply passing `TResult` does not mean that the other generic types are resolved (even though logically, they can be).

Depending on how much you can change your definitions, you *can* make a bit tidier:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static TResult LoadFromAnySource<TResult>(this ConfigurationSection section, string serviceBaseUri, string nodeName)
        where TResult : IDatabaseConfigurable<object, ConfigurationSection>, new()
    {
        return default(TResult);
    }
}

public class ConfigurationSection { }
public interface IDatabaseConfigurable<out TContract, out TSection> 
    where TContract : new()
    where TSection : ConfigurationSection
{ 
}

public class DatabaseConfigurable<TContract, TSection> : IDatabaseConfigurable<TContract, TSection>
    where TContract : new()
    where TSection : ConfigurationSection
{ 
}

public class SourceObserverContract { }
public class SourceObserverSection : ConfigurationSection { }
```

Which lets you write:

```
var sect = new ConfigurationSection();
sect.LoadFromAnySource<DatabaseConfigurable<SourceObserverContract, SourceObserverSection>>("a", "B");
```

The difference being you put the constraint on the `IDatabaseConfigurable`, rather than on the method. You also need to make the interface covariant. If that is not possible with your design, then it is not possible, as far as I can see, to do what you're trying to accomplish (without having a non-generic `IDatabaseConfigurable`)

Comment: I know, but sometimes it can be avoided with extracting some type on class level. For example `Foo.Bar<A,B,C>(B b, C c)` when we can infer `B` and `C` make us to specify all arguments, but `Foo<A>.Bar(B b, C c)` can avoid it. But I don't see how can I make same (or similar) trick here...

Comment: In this case, no, since all types are coming from the generic arguments (except for `ConfigurationSection`, which I did move - the same idea as your example here). Since we don't pass the types, it is impossible without having a covarient interface, or a non-generic interface

Comment: I upvote it but unfortunly I cannot use it becuase callee should get a final result as an exact type. It can cast it, of course, but It's better when covariance does everything for us.